# TurboPower Abbrevia in C++Builder2009

Tags: zip, c++builder, abbrevia

I want install TurboPower Abbrevia 3.05 from http://sourceforge.net/projects/tpabbrevia/ but its not working. :(

docu says:

_4. Open & compile the runtime package specific to the IDE being
used (e.g. B305vr2007.dpk for Delphi2007)

Start C++Builder2009 -> "Open Project..", select "B305vr2009.dpk" and click "open", but nothing happen. What is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have RAD Studio, and only have C++Builder, you'll have to build it via the command line:

```
dcc32 -JL B305vr2009.dpk
```

You can then import the .bpl file generated from the Component->Import Component menu.

Answer (score 0):

It's nice to see that someone is finally working on Abbrevia again, but looking at the Abbrevia web site I see that it still doesn't support modern versions of C++Builder. A few years ago I need to create Zips in an application and I found out that Abbrevia wouldn't work for me anymore. So, I compiled and linked in the Zip library from [Info-ZIP](http://info-zip.org/), which worked very well. I didn't have much trouble adapting it to C++Builder as I recall, and it's still working fine today.

Info-ZIP's library only works with Zip files (no 7zip, etc.) but that's all we need here.

Answer (score 0):

Abbrevia 3.05 didn't have C++Builder packages.  The current release (5.0) supports C++Builder 2009-XE2 and has native .cbproj packages for it.